# Azure Stream Analytics CreateOrReplace Transformation Conflict or Bad Request

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics

We are currently streaming data from an Azure Event Hub via Azure Stream Analytics to Cosmos DB. I want to be able to programatically change the query (/ Transformation) that is completed as the data is streamed.

```
var existingQuery = AnalyticsClient.Transformations.Get(handler.ResourceGroup, handler.JobName, handler.JobName);

if (job.JobState == "Started")
        {
            AnalyticsClient.StreamingJobs.BeginStopAsync(handler.ResourceGroup, handler.JobName).Wait();
        }
        var transformation = new Transformation()
        {
            Query = $@"SELECT 
                        [key] as partition_key
                    INTO[{outputName}]
                    FROM Input",
            StreamingUnits = 1
        }; 
AnalyticsClient.Transformations.CreateOrReplace(transformation, handler.ResourceGroup, handler.JobName, handler.JobName);
```

[Stream Analytics Job Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1k0cA.png) - Transformations shows as null.

It is unclear what the default name of the transformation might be but **trying to get a transformation** (of the same name as the job) from a job:

```
{
    "code": "NotFound",
    "message": "StreamAnalytics_Prototype_2 does not exist in Stream Analytics job 'StreamAnalytics_Prototype_2' in resource group 'removed' in subscription 'removed'.",
    "details": {
        "code": "404",
        "message": "StreamAnalytics_Prototype_2 does not exist in Stream Analytics job 'StreamAnalytics_Prototype_2' in resource group 'removed' in subscription 'removed'.",
        "correlationId": "removed",
        "requestId": "removed"
    }
}
```

**Trying to create a transformation**:

```
{
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "The number of transformations defined for this job exceeds the maximum limit of 1 that is supported.",
    "details": {
        "code": "400",
        "message": "The number of transformations defined for this job exceeds the maximum limit of 1 that is supported."
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create the transformation from Azure portal, the default name is for the transformation "Transformation". If you create the transformation from SDK, you need to specific the name in code.

```
streamAnalyticsManagementClient.Transformations.CreateOrReplace(transformation, resourceGroupName, streamingJobName, transformationName);
```

By the way, I found the default transformation name from Activity log after added a query from Azure portal.

[image]

Comment: That is great thanks; this was also useful: var streamingjob = AnalyticsClient.StreamingJobs.Get(ResourceGroup, JobName, "transformation");

Comment: I also had a Stream under which the query was named script (I assume a dev created it via .net), I was able to check via the above method in the activity log.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Powershell or CloudPowershell to get the transformation name by using `Get-AzStreamAnalyticsJob`. In my case, there were multiple jobs and I needed to find the transformation name for the first job in the list.

```
$ (Get-AzStreamAnalyticsJob -expand 'Transformation')[0].TransformationName
```

I couldn't find the transformation name in Azure portal though.